# Enqueue jquery in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im having some trouble adding jquery libraries to a custom wordpress plugin.
It's telling me it cant find variable jQuery.
Any help is much appreciated.

`simplepluginclass.php` includes `functions.php`

`include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .  'inc/functions.php';`

**functions.php**

```
 <?php
        function register_jqscripts() {
            wp_enqueue_script('jQuery', 'http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery');
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
            wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
        }


    function add_datepicker(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#dob').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'register_form', 'register_jqscripts' );
    add_action('register_form','add_datepicker');

?>
```

**simplepluginclass.php**

```
 <label for="dob"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'sportspress' ) ?><br />
               <input type="date" class="customdatepicker" id="dob" name="dob" />
          </label>
```

Comment: Who is "it" that is telling you something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [link](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) that you're referencing for jQuery is pointing to the *Google Code* documentation. Change the link to point to the `jQuery` source file on the CDN:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
```

Comment: thanks that was the jquery problem. sorry i totally missed that i was pointing to documentation. thanks.

Comment: for some reason the datepicker is not loading in safari but its working now in chrome. i guess it might be a cacheing issue.